# Open link in WebView Swift

Tags: swift, webview, webkit

How to open link from webView to safari? I have this webView and when i open it i cant open any link from text from webView

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample implementation of how you can open webview in your app

Add the following to header/import

```
import SafariServices
```

Function to open weburl

```
func openWebURL(url : URL) {
      let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
      present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can call the function as below

```
self.openWebURL(url: webUrl)
```

Hope this helps